# wordpress favicon not working properly on all browsers

Tags: html, wordpress, google-chrome, opera, favicon

Question link on wordpress stackoverflow https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/302693/140614

---

Curious fact: the favicon works only on admin dashboard on chrome/opera.

I've tried to clean the cache, but still not work. The line of code to the favicon its being included, buts it just doesnt work

[image: favicon including code]

I'm including the favicon through admin panel, to be dynamic. I just dont want to include it direct on the code.

- Firefox (Works)
- Edge (Works)
- Tor (Works)
- Chrome (Works only on admin dashboard)
- Opera (Works only on admin dashboard)

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using plugin for this? I think it wont work on Safari as well.

Comment: I've made the same think on other websites and the favicon works, with no need of a specific plugin. But what a plugin has to do with it? 
does wordpress not have the means to deal with it naturally?

Comment: Not entirely sure why your Favicon is not showing in certain browsers.  Something similar happened to me a while back.  Sometimes it is easier to simply remove all references of the image (Original image and any associated thumbnails) and re-upload it.  To ensure the image/thumbnails are completely removed, delete directly from your web files rather than just through WP Dashboard > Media.

Comment: WP handlee favicon's but sometimes its better to use plugin designed to do this. But this is only my opinion.